# simulate real traffic Load testing

Tags: load-testing

The Client asked me to do a load test to see if autoscaling works fine, so used AB from few servers and start hitting it with requests. eventually, the whole thing scaled up to 10 t2.micrs and was serving 63k requests per min. When i proudly told him about the results he told me that tests with AB is shit. I need to simulate real users. Now i have no idea how to simulate real users to that many requests.

Any suggestions?

is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try jmeter (http://jmeter.apache.org).

First you emulate a user's navigation capturing your browse of the site and then *play* it as many times as you want (may require to tweak a bit here and there). Also, you can do much more (checking for certain results, changing the input for every test, etc)